# NSURLConnection start + autorelease

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, autorelease

In my app I have to make a HTTP call and I am not interested in the response result from the web service. So I was wondering if it is OK to create a connection and start it and autorelease it not to cause a memory leak.

```
NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:nil];
[connection start];
[connection autorelease];
```

Is it possible that the garbage collection could destroy the connection object before the HTTP call is made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question. Even if it is not stated explicitly that the NSURLConnection is retained by the operating system, it appears obvious that the connection request is added as a source of the run loop and then, as such, retained.
In any case it should be better for you to set a minimum delegate for the request by just observing the connection termination with

```
connectionDidFinishLoading:
```

and after that release your connection object, as written in this part of the documentation:

Finally, if the connection succeeds in downloading the request, the delegate receives the connectionDidFinishLoading: message. The delegate will receive no further messages for the connection **and the NSURLConnection object can be released.**

For the same reason you should observe the end of connection due to an error with

```
connection:didFailWithError:
```

.

Comment: I know that the normal workflow requires that the connection is released after the response is acquired. Testing with the delegation is not a sure thing. Only a negative result will be definitive. And if I get a few positive answers with an autoreleased connection does not mean that is OK to do so.

Comment: viggio, that's a superb answer!

Comment: Akshay : thanks
Teodor: this is the point, the delegate approach is safe, not using the delegate could lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

It is understandable that you don't require the response from the server. But don't you want to ensure that a connection was established? What if the connection times out? The client will not even get to know about the error. I feel it is better that you release the connection instance after you have confirmed the the request reached the server.

Also, calling `start` in your case is not required, as you are not using `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` method with NO for the `startImmediately` parameter.